# How do I make the font size of text inside an H1 dynamically fill the entire width of the H1 with CSS alone?

Tags: html, css

I have an h1

```
<h1>Title Of Thing<h1>
```

The h1 is 200px width

```
h1{width:200px;}
```

While the h1 is indeed 200px wide, the text inside of the h1 does not fit that entire width.

I would expect to be able to make font-size 100%

```
h1{font-size:100%;}
```

But of course that only makes the font-size 100% of the default and has nothing to do with the h1 container.

I need the font size inside of the h1 to dynamically fit the width of the H1 because I want to change the width of the h1 sometimes.  This means that the hight of the h1 of course needs to adapt so that the text does not get clipped.

I am disappointed that this is not the default behavior of H tags.

There is something called fit-content which does the exact opposite of what I need.

```
h1{width: fit-content;}
```

This makes the h1 shrink to the size of the text inside of it. But I need the text to expand to the size of the H1.

Comment: some research led me to some solution of adding the text inside the h1 tags as an svg but that did not help because when changing the text just a little I have to adjust the viewspace of the svg to fit the text manually and it came back to the same problem again.

I have also seen people come up with fancy solutions using JavaScript, but I am holding out for a css/html solution.

Maybe h1 is not the best thing to use?  is there another tag that works this way , label , table-label etc?

Comment: It is also sad that I can use font-size: 100vw for the view-port but there is no such thing as font-size:100cw for the width of the container.  You would think that font-size:100% would be 100cw but font-size 100% is not the same as width:100% which is so frustrating.  CSS needs CW and CH and CMIN CMAX just like vh vw vmax vmin.  

That would be the answer to my question cause I could just do font-size:100cw

Comment: transform: scale( ); might have something promising if I could scale(100%-container-width)  /not viewport width but container width/ ALSO, scale scales from the center and then a transform is needed to re-center the text.  It is annoying and clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is something called container queries.
The following code made the text inside the h1 scale to the full width of the h1 responsively.

```
h1{
container-type: inline-size;
font-size: 12cqw;
}
```